# How to set object /variable to request scope using PHP

Tags: php

I am java, j2ee developer. But new to PHP lang.

In Java Controller and Jsp , there is provision to add object in request attribute. 
like this ....

```
request.setAttribute("Object_key", Object);
```

Is there is such kind of provision in PHP, which add object/Variable in request.
So these objects/Variables are available to next view page.

Comment: `next view page`? So you're talking about sessions?

Comment: Not necessarily - request scoped variables will live to the destination of a request, or the next page. Session scope is bigger and will include every page no matter where they're set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$_REQUEST["username"] = "Tom";
```

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: If it worked for you, please mark it as an answer, so other can benefit from it. Thanks...

Comment: Just make sure not to overwrite fields set by the request itself (by PHP)

Comment: @raoulsson - That is not an issue. $_REQUEST, $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE are different arrays. Changing one does not affect the others.